# solr: Create filter query with a function

Tags: function, solr, filtering

One of the values returned by my solr query is a calculated value (using solr 4.0).  The function is

```
sum(product(2,preis12_0_3),preis34_0_3)
```

Now I would like to filter the resultset on the values returned by the function, but I get this error:

```
undefined field text
```

Is it possible to filter on a function?  Any pointers in the right direction appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Filter query do support function queries with [FunctionRangeQParserPlugin](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_3_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/search/FunctionRangeQParserPlugin.html)

e.g. `Filter query example: fq={!frange l=0 u=2.2}sum(user_ranking,editor_ranking)`

undefined field text -> Would be the case for the field not being defined in the schema.xml